# How to validate annotations during build or during startup on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Let's say, for example, that I have a `@TimedMillis` and a `@TimedSeconds` annotation. What they do is log the method execution duration time, one in milliseconds and the other in seconds.

It would not make any sense to have them both on the same method. A method can have one of these annotations, or he can have none of them, but not them both at the same time.

How can I check that a method does not have them both during build (preferably)? If not possible during build, how can I do this during startup and prevent application from starting? I have seen hibernate doing this during startup. Although it didn't prevent the application from starting, it did prevent the application from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reflections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections) library to easily scan a package and all its subpackages for classes that contain methods annotated with a specific annotation.

You can then inject the validation logic wherever you see fit.

For example you could:

1. Add the reflections dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Add the validation logic, even earlier than Spring Boot bootstrap if you want, like so:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateAnnotations();
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
  }

  private static void validateAnnotations() {
    Set<Method> annotatedMethods = 
      new Reflections("com.example", new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
      .getMethodsAnnotatedWith(TimedMillis.class);
    
    annotatedMethods.stream()
    .filter(method -> method.getDeclaredAnnotationsByType(TimedSeconds.class).length > 0)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(method -> {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid annotations for method " + method);
    });
  }
```

Comment: It worked as expected. I have made [this public repo on github](https://github.com/Chuque/annotation-validation) with my implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is also alternative option - by making it impossible by annotation itself.
This approach assumes that both @TimedMillis and a @TimedSeconds are actually very similar - and can be refactored to a single annotation.
To achieve such functionality new annotation can be introduced - that will have the desired timeunit as the value provided.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Timed {

    /**
     * Defines time unit of duration.
     *
     * @return duration time unit
     */
    TimeUnit timeUnit();
}
```

It will help to achieve needed functionality as duplicate annotations are not allowed (only if not marked with @Repeatable)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) to do this validation. The annotation processing will occur at build time. Here is a nice tutorial on how to use the annotation processing API: https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder